# differentiating $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}/x$

Tags: calculus

So I am not sure what I need to do to differentiate this problem. Do I use a combination of chain rule and product rule, and if so what would it look like? Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the numerator $\sqrt{x} + 1$ or $\sqrt{x + 1}$?

Comment: it is the second one

Comment: As Null said, parentheses please.  Either way, you need the rule for fractions first.  After that, it looks like you may need the chain rule if you have $\sqrt {x+1}$, else the power rule will do what you need.  If you show some work, we may be able to find the problem.  What have you done?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the quotient rule, or you can recognize that

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x} = x^{-1}\sqrt{x+1}$$

and use the product rule $(g \cdot h)' = g' \cdot h + g \cdot h'$. With $g = x^{-1}$ and $h = \sqrt{x+1}$, using the product rule you get

$$f'(x) = \frac{x^{-1}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}-x^{-2}\sqrt{x+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use the quotient rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule and also technically the chain rule but since the derivative of $x+1$ is $1$ it doesn't really matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will use the quotient rule and the chain rule. The quotient rule is:

For $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'$ = $\frac{g(x)(f(x))'-f(x)(g(x))'}{(g(x))^{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Quotient Rule derives the fraction. Chain rule derives the $\sqrt{x+1}$

The quotient rule (if you dont know it) is : $$\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}}} \right) = \frac{{\frac{d}{{dx}}f\left( x \right)g\left( x \right) - f\left( x \right)\frac{d}{{dx}}g\left( x \right)}}{{g^2 \left( x \right)}}$$